# extractin/building boost program_options

Tags: c++, boost

I have successfully installed boost, compiled binaries, and built bcp.  I have also been able to extract the regex library using bcp.  After doing this, I found a gcc_gen.sh script and bunch of makefiles under

`my_exported_boost_regex/libs/regex/build/`

and used one of them to make

```
my_exported_boost_regex/libs/regex/build/gcc/libboost_regex-gcc-1_43.a
```

This is the library I use in my code and everything works great.

Now I want to do the same thing for program_options but after I extract all the files using bcp, I'm confused as to what to do next.  The only file available under

`my_exported_boost_program_options/libs/program_options/build/`

is `Jamfile.v2` and I can't for the life of me figure out how to use that to build the binary.  It seems to me something is missing here.

Appreciate your help.
Thanks,

J

Comment: Post the arguments you are giving to bcp

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured out that I have to include "build" in addition to my libraries of interest in the bcp call like this:

```
bcp program_options build ../my_exported_boost_program_options/
```

This apparently places the appropriate bjam config files in the exported dir and I can then call bjam from that directory and build my exported libs.

J

Answer (score 1):

you have to build boost from toplevel directory with bjam. Please refer to the [Getting Started Docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install)

Comment: I did build boost as you describe and all the binaries were created.  But these binaries are not exported by bcp, so presumably they need to be built again, which is what I did for regex lib.  I can't figure out how to do it for program_options

Comment: Sorry, i'm not familiar with bcp.

Comment: While the binaries are not exported by bcp, you can copy them manually rather then building them afresh.