# I'm lost in boost libraries (specifically boost_program_options)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

Hi all I've been banging my head against the wall all day now.

So I want to move my program onto the university supercomputer, but it doesn't have boost (and I used boost program_options in my code). On my pc, I just have -lboost_program_options and that works fine, but obviously won't work anymore.

So, I need to package the necessary stuff along with my code so that it will compile on the supercomputer (using intel icpc)

My first hurdle was compiling the line in my makefile that had the code that wanted to include the  boost header, but I ran the following in my code folder:

```
bcp --scan --boost=/usr/include/ main.cpp destination_folder/
```

And put the resulting files in my include directory. which solved that.

Boost program options isn't a header only package unfortunately, so i need something else. I need to get a library or something. Because i get errors when the compiler gets to the last task on my makefile (doing all the object files)

In my travels I found this question:

[extractin/building boost program_options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269785/extractin-building-boost-program-options)

I tried what the answer suggests, but putting "build" in my command doesn't generate any extra files...

Now totally stuck, don't know how to get this library thing. I've read so much stuff on bjam  my head is spinning, I just don't have the level of understanding to process it all in my head.

OS: Linux both systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to build boost on that machine. Install it in your home. Change your CXXFLAGS and LDDFLAGS to point to the proper header and library directories and build your code there.
The other option is to cross compile both on your PC (if you have such a cross toolchain). Link your code statically to boost and take the final binary to the super computer.

Comment: Ok thanks, I downloaded the boost, moved it over to the SC and built it there, and linked it statically. I have compilation! It seems so easy, maybe my head was clearer today.

Answer (score 1):

Since both systems are linux, you'll just want to use the binaries. If both systems run on the same CPU, just compile your program statically. If not, download the debian package for the architecture your supercomputer runs on and rip headers and binaries from that.

I've build boost from bjam for cross-compiling to windows, and if there ever was a reason to use the autotools in a project, it's the mess of boost and bjam. Avoid it if possible, and try to adapt the debian package source if you can't.

Comment: +1 My guess is that he will want the extra optimizations the intel compiler can offer when the code is built there. gcc-4.4 is very close to the speed icc can offer but still lags (at least on intel Xeons).

Comment: @thiton, I don't really understand several things sorry. I'm not aware of them running the same cpu or not. I know that i am required to compile with intel on the supercomputer but I have g++ on my linux pc. I don't know how to "rip" the binaries from the debian pacakage (do you mean the program_options package?) I think this last bit is my main problem.

Comment: @long404 , you are correct in that i have to use the intel compiler (my guess is that they want the programs to be more optimised so that they take less time, freeing up the system for other users). see above comment for more clarification on my troubles

Comment: @CptLightning: When you are required to build with the icc, well, that's too bad - sorry, I don't know much about that. "Rip the binaries" means that you install the package and just copy /usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so from your computer. After all, the program options hopefully aren't performance-critical, but I assume that the icc has incompatible name-mangling with the gcc.

Comment: Do you need the optimizations icc can offer or just need your code to run there?

Comment: @thiton ripping and compiling against them would be a pain in the arse if he doesn't know much about linkage.

Comment: @CptLightning: icc has a trial version you can download. Build your code on your machine with icc (linking statically against boost_program_options) and then just upload the binaries on that uni machine. They should be binary compatible if you link everything statically ("ldd your_binary" shows no dependencies).

Comment: @long404 , I don't think I can link everything statically. I am using openmp and I couldn't get that to work statically

Comment: @thiton , I tried copying over my libboost_program_options.so (also tried .a) but I get messages like: ....so: undefined reference to '_ZSt16_.....etc...

Comment: @CptLightning: Yeah, that's the incompatible name-mangling. Well, so much for that, you'll have to suffer bjam. Good luck.

Comment: @thiton: can't you make whoever manages these machines to install boost there? boost is so freaking popular, use that argument.
Read my post below. still two options: compiling boost on that super comp, or (probably harder) cross compiling both boost and your code.
BTW: you don't need to compile statically to libs that are available on that machine as long as the versions on both machines match.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building `Boost.ProgramOptions` you could include and compile all its .cpp files within your project.

Comment: one thing is that I don't know where the relevant cpp files are. I can see .so and .a files in /usr/lib and hpp files in /usr/local/ ....

Comment: They need not be present in your system. Download the sources from the website, the relevant cpp files are located at `./boost_1_47_0/libs/program_options/src`, note that some of them are for Windows.